# Why does Django show NoReverseMatch at /articles/3/ Reverse for 'article_edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Whenever I try to link `Edit` (`article_edit.html`) and `Delete` (`article_detail.html`), Django shows this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /articles/3/
Reverse for 'article_edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['articles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/3/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'article_edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['articles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
```

I tried without linking these tags (`Edit` and `Delete`) and the app runs absolutely fine, but whenever I add these lines of codes the app stop working. Here's my `article_detail.html` template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
<div class="article-entry">
  <h2>{{object.title}}</h2>
  <p>by {{object.author}} | {{object.date}}</p>
  <p>{{object.body}}</p>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'article_edit' article.pk %}">Edit</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'article_delete' article.pk %}">Delete</a>
</p>
<p>back to <a href="{% url 'article_list' %}"></a>All Articles</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

Here are `models.py`, `urls.py` and `views.py` for 'articles' app:

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse


class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article_detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.urls.base import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView

from .models import Articles


class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = "article_list.html"


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = "article_detail.html"


class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Articles
    fields = (
        "title",
        "body",
    )
    template_name = "article_edit.html"


class ArticleDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = "article_delete.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("article_list"
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ArticleListView,
    ArticleUpdateView,
    ArticleDeleteView,
    ArticleDetailView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path("", ArticleListView.as_view(), name="article_list"),
    path("<int:pk>/edit/", ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name="article_edit"),
    path("<int:pk>/", ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article_detail"),
    path("<int:pk>/delete/", ArticleDeleteView.as_view(), name="article_delete"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your template you're trying to access a pk that does not exist.
Try changing "article.pk" to "object.id".